# CGAL Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization contract_until_convergence function produces branches that does not exist in input polygon

Tags: cgal

I use contract_until_convergence function from CGAL Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization to produce skeleton from input polygon.

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/classCGAL_1_1Mean__curvature__flow__skeletonization.html

[image]

In some cases the skeleton creates branches (see top of the image above, skeleton in red color) that does not exist in input polygon. Is there some parameters to set to prevent this ?

```
using Skeletonization = CGAL::Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization<Polyhedron>;

Skeletonization mean_curve_skeletonizer(polyhedron);

mean_curve_skeletonizer.contract_until_convergence();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parameters controlling the quality of the skeleton:

- [`quality_speed_tradeoff()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/classCGAL_1_1Mean__curvature__flow__skeletonization.html#a2ae47df3c89d85e94732b0debc175c1f)
- [`medially_centered_speed_tradeoff()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/classCGAL_1_1Mean__curvature__flow__skeletonization.html#a7e356f5e103302174a6531e89b924197)

Also one thing that affect the skeleton is the sampling of the input surface that is used to compute Voronoi poles. In the original papers, it is said: *Given  a  sufficiently  good  sampling, the Voronoi poles [ACK00] form a provably convergent sampling of the medial axis*.

> [ACK00]AMENTAN.,  CHOIS.,  KOLLURIR.  K.:   The powercrust, unions of balls, and the medial axis transform. Computational Geometry: Theory and Applications 19(2000), 127–153.3

You can use the function [`isotropic_remeshing`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html) with a sufficiently small target edge length to improve the Voronoi pole computation.